# First time POCO C++ library use on Gentoo

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, gentoo

I installed POCO via emerge and on very first attempt to compile I am getting

```
undefined reference to `Poco::RefCountedObject::RefCountedObject()
```

Which clearly indicated it is not finding the libraries.
Doesn't emerge do the linking for you?

How doing I compile or properly link POCO in Gentoo so it finds the libs?

```
#include "Poco/ActiveMethod.h"
#include "Poco/ActiveResult.h"
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using Poco::ActiveMethod;
using Poco::ActiveResult;

class ActiveAdder
{
public:
    ActiveAdder(): add(this, &ActiveAdder::addImpl)
    {
    }

    ActiveMethod<int, std::pair<int, int>, ActiveAdder> add;

private:
    int addImpl(const std::pair<int, int>& args)
    {
        return args.first + args.second;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ActiveAdder adder;

    ActiveResult<int> sum = adder.add(std::make_pair(1, 2));
    // do other things
    sum.wait();
    std::cout << sum.data() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We will need more information: how are you compiling? Also " Doesn't emerge do the linking for you and I just #include?" what does that mean? How have you installed the Poco library? etc etc

Comment: @JaviV Yes, the libraries are installed via emerge  dev-libs/poco 1.4.5-r1   Description:         C++ class libraries that simplify and accelerate the development of network-centric, portable applications

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use QT websockets!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

POCO gentoo ebuild have use flags, which enable some parts of POCO.

```
feniks@charlotte  ~  equery uses poco
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for dev-libs/poco-1.6.0:
 U I
 + + 7z                : <unknown>
 + + apache2           : Add Apache2 support
 + + cppparser         : <unknown>
 + + crypto            : <unknown>
 + + data              : <unknown>
 + + doc               : Add extra documentation (API, Javadoc, etc). It is recommended to enable per package instead
                         of globally
 + + file2pagecompiler : <unknown>
 - - iodbc             : Add support for iODBC library
 + + json              : <unknown>
 - - mongodb           : <unknown>
 + + mysql             : Add mySQL Database support
 + + net               : <unknown>
 - - odbc              : Add ODBC Support (Open DataBase Connectivity)
 + + pagecompiler      : <unknown>
 + + pdf               : Add general support for PDF (Portable Document Format), this replaces the pdflib and cpdflib
                         flags
 + + sqlite            : Add support for sqlite - embedded sql database
 + + ssl               : Add support for Secure Socket Layer connections
 + + tests             : <unknown>
 + + util              : <unknown>
 + + xml               : Add support for XML files
 + + zip               : <unknown>
```

Also, you should link your program with poco itself. All basic classes in PocoFoundation (like in your case).

For example, here it is my link flags (generated by CMake):

```
test.o /usr/lib64/libPocoJSON.so.30 /usr/lib64/libPocoXML.so.30 -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_locale-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt cpsp/libtinyhttp_cpsp.a api/libtinyhttp_api.a /usr/lib64/libPocoFoundation.so.1.6.0 -lpcre -lz -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lexpat
```